# DB2 REORG TABLE from client side with Migrator.NET

Tags: c#, db2, alter-table, migratordotnet

I'm using [Migrator.NET](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/) with a DB2 database and my current migration executes an `ALTER TABLE` statement, which causes the table to go into the "reorg pending state". This state requires the reorganisation of the table with `> REORG TABLE TableName` before I can do anything else with it.

I tried executing this with

> Database["DB2"].ExecuteNonQuery("REORG TABLE MyTable");

but it failed because apparently the `REORG` command is server side only and can't be called from the client. Then I tried creating a stored procedure which calls the REORG statement but am struggling with the correct syntax.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
Database["DB2"].ExecuteNonQuery("call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD ('REORG TABLE MyTable')");
```

[Link to ADMIN_CMD documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0012547.htm)

In DB2 9.7 it's also possible to use this procedure: [ADMIN_REVALIDATE_DB_OBJECTS()](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0053626.html)